# Create a contour plot from netCDF-data

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm trying to do a contour plot with the days (1-31 days) as x, altitude as y, and amplitude as z. For every day, there is 18 amplitudes for 18 different altitudes.

First, the code for getting the 18 values for one day is the following:

```
def sine_func(x, a):
    return a * np.sin((np.pi / 180) * x)
def oneday(data):
  for i in range(0,36,2):
      #temp = data.variables['t'][4, 36-i, -68, 0:359]
      #meridional = data.variables['v'][4, 36-i, -68, 0:359]
      zonal = data.u.values[4][36-i][-68][0:359]
      longitude = data.lon[0:359]
      z = data.z.values[4][36-i][-68][292]
      LongList = []
      ZonalList = []
      for j in range(0, len(zonal)):
          ZonalList.append(zonal[j])
          LongList.append(longitude[j])
          j = j + 1
      popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(sine_func, LongList, ZonalList)
      height.append(z)
      poptabs = abs(popt)
      poptlist = poptabs.tolist()
      amplitude.append(poptlist)
  return height, amplitude
```

This works as it should. Then comes the one code where I do it for january (which doesn't work)

```
def onemonth(datalist):
    height_month = [0]*31
    amplitude_month = [0]*31
    #daynumber = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
    for k in range(len(datalist)):
        dat = xr.open_dataset(datalist[k])
        height, amplitude = oneday(dat)
        height_month.append(height)
        amplitude_month.append(amplitude)
        #y, z = np.meshgrid(height_month[k], amplitude_month[k])
        #day = k+1
        #ax.contour3D(day,y,z,50,cmap='binary')
        #plt.show()
    #height_month_array = np.array(height_month)
    #amplitude_month_array = np.array(amplitude_month)
    return height_month, amplitude_month


height_jan, amplitude_jan = onemonth(jan)

plt.contour(daysjan, height_jan, amplitude_jan)
plt.show()
```

"daysjan" from the plotting is a 31 (days in january)*18(values of each day, example [1,1,1,.]) list with the daynumber. I have also tried making a meshgrid of the height and amplitudes.
Error message:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (61,) + inhomogeneous part.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `daysjan`, `height_jan`, and `amplitude_jan`?

Comment: Hi @sj123 - welcome to Stack Overflow! To get the best responses here, please try to cut down your problem to the simplest possible [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See this guide to [asking a good question](/help/how-to-ask). and when asking about errors, be sure to post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) and [format as a code block](/help/formatting). thanks!